# Strange Facebook Post Behavior with Link

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is a sample of parameters I am providing when making a post to a user's wall.

[image]

This seems to work. However, I do not want a "sharing link" type of wall post, which this seems to create.

Here's the strangeness, and I'm hoping someone can help.

When I remove the "link" parameter, then suddenly the links in the wall post go to a facebook error page with code 191. In addition, as part of the URL it is going to, it has redirect_uri set to the picture url I provided.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Bottom line is this: I'd like a wall post that isn't "wrapped" in a sharing link wall post--I just want to post a message with a picture and have the links go to my facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a **big** picture on the timeline, the only way to do this from an app is to use an Open Graph *action*. However, the photo **must** be user-generated otherwise Facebook will reject your OG action request.